# How to perform a unit test on the controller layer in a nodejs project with mocha and sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, tsyringe

I'm creating an API as a study.
I'm very new to programming.
I wanted to unit test the controller layer using mocha. I'm using dependency injection with the tsyringe library.
In the test I wanted to stub the service layer, and apparently it's not working.

So the test is not working.
I tried countless ways, and perhaps due to lack of knowledge, none of them worked.
What would be the correct way to implement this test?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work..

```
sinon.stub(service, 'method').resolves() // if method does not return promise, use .returns()
```

Comment: tks! it's working.
Sorry for my terrible English, I'm Brazilian and I don't know any English.